# eslint returns errors but Github action is still successful

Tags: eslint, github-actions

I set up the following Github action:

```
name: Node.js CI

on: pull_request

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install scraper dependencies
      working-directory: ./scraper
      run: npm ci
    - name: Run linting in scraper
      working-directory: ./scraper
      run: npm run lint
```

The action run when the PR is created, but the checks are successful although eslint returns errors:
[image]

How can I make the action fail if there are errors from the linter?

Comment: It looks like it's running `eslint . || true` — can you try removing the `|| true` (which is causing the command to successfully exit regardless)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the command invoked by `npm run lint` is `eslint . || true`. Because of this, the `|| true` is causing the command to always finish with success (exit code 0). By removing it, the exit code will be whatever `eslint` returns, which is a nonzero exit code when there are errors.